# ActiveRecord Query Interface - Association with conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a `Post` model that `has_many :comments`. The question is: how can I build a query using *ActiveRecord Query Interface* that retrieves all posts and the **last comment** of each posts?

All I have right now is the following, but it doesn't filter the comments and I have no idea of what to do next:

```
Post.includes(:comments)
```

Comment: I think what you are looking for is Post.includes(:comments => :posts) ??

Comment: Nope, i need only the last `comment` made, not all of them.

Comment: Gotcha, sorry -- Read that wrong. Wrote an answer below. Should solve the issue, not sure if its a c/p solution for you -- but I think its the easiest way to accomplish what you are looking for. Just be careful with too large of a query. No need to lazy load data not being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the simplest thing comes to mind, which may not be the best is creating a scope.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    # has_many or maybe a has_one ? I don't have time to fire up console again to check, sorry!
    has_many :last_comment, :class_name => 'Comment', :limit => 1, :order => 'comments.created_at DESC'
end
```

And then use

```
Post.includes(:last_comment)
```

Be sure you have indexes in your SQL.

Comment: Well, it didn't work. I believe `includes` expects and association, not a scope. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Sorry, try changing the "scope" command to "has_many" or a "has_one" -- should do the trick. I didn't reload my console before testing, my mistake!